# Is cron running?

Tags: cron

Is there an easy way to tell if cron is actually running? I'm not talking about whether my crontab entries are valid, but *is cron actually attempting to execute those entries*?

I'm on Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.04 (which uses `upstart`) you can check the service status using `service cron status`:

```
$ service cron status
cron start/running, process 1414
```

The `systemd` equivalent (applicable for newer systems) is `systemctl status cron.service`

You could also examine the `CRON` entries in the system log, e.g. `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: This needs to run with elevated permissions. It might be necessary to run `sudo service cron status`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status of cron service or any service for that matter using

```
service service.name status
```

In case of cron

```
service cron status
```